# ¿Es segura esta configuración con Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirección

Tengo la siguiente estructura en Codeigniter:

[image: Estructura]

Entonces, lo que hago para poder acceder a mis recursos estáticos (js,css,libs,etc), es con un re-direccionamiento:

```
redirect('../public/home.html','location',null);
```

en el controller principal, eso esta bien?
Porque solo quiero ocupar Codeigniter como api rest y en mi carpeta public tengo js para consumir dicha api.

Comment: La pregunta parece basada en opiniones, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: No encuentro la utilidad de esos redireccionamientos, ¿Cuál es la idea de usarlos?

Comment: CodeIgniter ocupa la carpeta 'view' para las vistas, pero yo no quiero ocupar php para las vistas, únicamente HTML, css y js , por eso hago que redireccione a la carpeta public, dónde tengo el 'cliente' que consume la api

Answer (score 1):

En **CodeIgniter** se utiliza la función *redirect* se utiliza para que tu sitio web vaya a la dirección que le estás declarando

Este es un ejemplo de cuando se usa *redirect* que básicamente al terminar la función *index* te envía a la página que declaraste

```
function index()
{
    redirect('admin/proyecto/pagina_proyecto');
}
```

Este es un ejemplo de como mandar a llamar un archivo js, css, etc.

Solo debes colocar la ruta a tus archivos.

```
<?php echo site_url('admin/proyecto/carpeta_js/style.js')?>
```

El **site_url** se configura previamente en tu archivo **config.php** por lo regular la ruta de este archivo es /application/config/config.php

Ahí se declara de esta forma

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://IP_ADDRESS/';
```